# SQL query to combine duplicate records and sum QTY

Tags: sql

I have an excel spreadsheet which pulls records from SQL. I want to combine the duplicate records and sum the qty field of matching records.
I tried adding a select(sum) and group by command to my existing query but I didn't get very far as I have no real SQL experience.
My table looks like this:

```
item no.| item description | qty   | date 
1         red onion          5       20110405 
2         yellow onion       5       20110406 
1         red onion          10      20110405
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
item no.| item description | qty   | date
1         red onion          15      20110405
2         yellow onion       5       20110406
```

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT 
     OELINHST_SQL.item_no, OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1, OELINHST_SQL.qty_ordered, oelinhst_sql.unit_weight,  OEHDRHST_SQL.shipping_dt, OEHDRHST_SQL.inv_dt
FROM
    OEHDRHST_SQL OEHDRHST_SQL,
    OELINHST_SQL OELINHST_SQL
WHERE
    OEHDRHST_SQL.ord_type *= OELINHST_SQL.ord_type AND
    OEHDRHST_SQL.ord_no *= OELINHST_SQL.ord_no AND
    (OELINHST_SQL.prod_cat <> '26' AND
    OELINHST_SQL.prod_cat <> '25') AND
    OELINHST_SQL.loc = 'fs2' AND 
    OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1 IS NOT NULL AND 
    OEHDRHST_SQL.shipping_dt >= 20110101 AND
    OELINHST_SQL.item_no NOT IN ('800-505-00', '800-083-00', '800-506-00', '400-511-39')  AND (OELINHST_SQL.item_no NOT BETWEEN '800-000-00' AND '999-999-99')
ORDER BY
    OELINHST_SQL.item_no ASC,
    OEHDRHST_SQL.inv_dt DESC
```

Comment: The words you are looking for are [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)

Comment: You're sample data makes it look like you have just one table, but the query is clearly referencing two tables. Can you give us all the details for your particular case?

Comment: The query that you have doesn't have the same columns listed as your results indicate. There are extra columns. Also, it would be helpful if you included what you tried when using SUM() and why it didn't work for you. Did you get an error? Wrong results? The SUM() is almost surely what you should be using.

Comment: Sorry, my exact table uses these fields: `item_no | item_desc_1 | qty_ordered |unit_weight |shipping_dt |inv_d` and then I add a field in excel where I convert the sql date to a format excel recognizes. 

Before, I attempted to use Sum and Group By like this
`SELECT OELINHST_SQL.item_no,OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1, (SELECT sum(OELINHST_SQL.qty_ordered)  FROM OELINHST_SQL group by OELINHST_SQL.item_no)
FROM OELINHST_SQL`
which was giving me a "Sub Query cannot return more than 1 value.." error.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause and `SUM` the relevant column.

Here's a simplified example that can be adapted to your situation.

```
select t1.name, t2.name, t2.date, sum(t2.orders)
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
group by t1.name, t2.name, t2.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add a group by clause, and add in SUM(Qty) and MIN(date)

Not too sure about your column names, but probably something like this:

```
SELECT 
     OELINHST_SQL.item_no, OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1, SUM(OELINHST_SQL.qty_ordered), oelinhst_sql.unit_weight,  MIN(OEHDRHST_SQL.shipping_dt), MIN(OEHDRHST_SQL.inv_dt)
FROM
    OEHDRHST_SQL OEHDRHST_SQL,
    OELINHST_SQL OELINHST_SQL
WHERE
    OEHDRHST_SQL.ord_type *= OELINHST_SQL.ord_type AND
    OEHDRHST_SQL.ord_no *= OELINHST_SQL.ord_no AND
    (OELINHST_SQL.prod_cat <> '26' AND
    OELINHST_SQL.prod_cat <> '25') AND
    OELINHST_SQL.loc = 'fs2' AND 
    OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1 IS NOT NULL AND 
    OEHDRHST_SQL.shipping_dt >= 20110101 AND
    OELINHST_SQL.item_no NOT IN ('800-505-00', '800-083-00', '800-506-00', '400-511-39')  AND (OELINHST_SQL.item_no NOT BETWEEN '800-000-00' AND '999-999-99')
GROUP BY OELINHST_SQL.item_no, OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1, oelinhst_sql.unit_weight
ORDER BY
    OELINHST_SQL.item_no ASC,
    OEHDRHST_SQL.inv_dt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
       OELINHST_SQL.item_no, 
       OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1, 
       SUM(OELINHST_SQL.qty_ordered),
       SUM(oelinhst_sql.unit_weight),  
       MIN(OEHDRHST_SQL.shipping_dt), 
       MIN(OEHDRHST_SQL.inv_dt)
    FROM
        OEHDRHST_SQL OEHDRHST_SQL,
        OELINHST_SQL OELINHST_SQL
    WHERE
        OEHDRHST_SQL.ord_type *= OELINHST_SQL.ord_type AND
        OEHDRHST_SQL.ord_no *= OELINHST_SQL.ord_no AND
        (OELINHST_SQL.prod_cat <> '26' AND
        OELINHST_SQL.prod_cat <> '25') AND
        OELINHST_SQL.loc = 'fs2' AND 
        OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1 IS NOT NULL AND 
        OEHDRHST_SQL.shipping_dt >= 20110101 AND
        OELINHST_SQL.item_no NOT IN ('800-505-00', '800-083-00', '800-506-00', '400-511-39')  AND (OELINHST_SQL.item_no NOT BETWEEN '800-000-00' AND '999-999-99')
    GROUP BY
       OELINHST_SQL.item_no, 
       OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1
    ORDER BY
        OELINHST_SQL.item_no ASC,
        OEHDRHST_SQL.inv_dt DESC
```

But, this assumes that shipping date and int_date will always be the same or that you want the earliest dates in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I added simpler table aliases to make it easier to read. Basically, you need to GROUP BY all columns that aren't included in an aggregate function.

```
SELECT 
  l.item_no
 ,l.item_desc_1
 ,SUM(l.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered
 ,l.unit_weight
 ,h.shipping_dt
 ,h.inv_dt
FROM OEHDRHST_SQL h
  LEFT OUTER JOIN OELINHST_SQL l ON h.ord_type = l.ord_type AND h.ord_no = l.ord_no
WHERE l.prod_cat <> '26'
  AND l.prod_cat <> '25'
  AND l.loc = 'fs2'
  AND l.item_desc_1 IS NOT NULL
  AND h.shipping_dt >= 20110101
  AND l.item_no NOT IN ('800-505-00', '800-083-00', '800-506-00', '400-511-39')
  AND l.item_no NOT BETWEEN '800-000-00' AND '999-999-99'
GROUP BY l.item_no, l.item_desc_1, l.unit_weight, h.shipping_dt, h.inv_dt
ORDER BY l.item_no ASC, h.inv_dt DESC
```

Comment: Rob, it seems your query does the trick! But theres one thing; is there a way I can exclude inv_dt from the Group By clause but still have it as part of the table? Essentially, I want to get the qty summed from every record with a matching item description, item no., and shipping_dt.

Comment: What would be the purpose of having inv_dt in the result set? If there are different values, which one would you pick for a given row? The rule is, it either needs to be included in the group by, or in an aggregate function. You could remove it and then use a MIN(inv_dt) or MAX(inv_dt) in the query. Hope that helps! 

P.S. If you like my answer, please upvote and accept. Thanks!